# Calling render before all js files are loaded so the owl carousel is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, carousel

I am loading all JS files using `SPComponentLoader` in ts file and I am using await for each load call.

Even then when I debug my code I observed it goes to render() in `.tsx` in between, executes that and after returning it will load the next JS file. Following is my code:

[image]

I am calling this function in `onInit()`:

```
public async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.loadCSS();
    this.loadScripts();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to deferred all js libraries loaded and re-render your data.

Sample demo:

```
Promise.all(
      [SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js'),
      SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js'),
      ]
    ).then(function(){
      //to do
    })
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I am new to this and I am not understanding how to use it.

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: When I am trying to re-render using setState, its giving error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. forceUpdate() also doesnt seem to be working. Is there any other way to re-render?